# Unable to override url link text using appendChild textNode

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page (one of many) each with an html table of 3 cells of headings (dimension, height, width) and 3 cells of values eg '100 by 50', 100, 50

I aim to create links at the base of the page to url examples with dimensions similar to these, slightly larger, slightly smaller.

I collect the numbers from the dynamically generated table and add or subtract to get the new values using:
`

```
    var $ = jQuery;
    $(function () {
    $('#table_1 tr').each(function() {
        var heightAdd1 = parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(1).html())+1;
        var heightLess1 = parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(1).html())-1;

        var widthAdd1 = parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(2).html())+1;
        var widthLess1 = parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(2).html())-1;
```

` etc.

I then place these into a new url link using:

```
$("a#heightAdd1widthAdd1").attr("href", "https://www.example.com/" + heightAdd1 + "-by-" + widthAdd1);
```

I want the link texts to show on the page as e.g. '101-by-51' '99-by-49' with whatever variation of numbers get generated.

On the html page I have `

```
<a id="heightAdd1widthAdd1" href="#">height+1 width+1</a><br>
<a id="heightLess1widthLess1" href="#">height-1 width-1</a>
```

`I try to overwrite this fixed text using:`

```
let textNode = document.createTextNode(heightAdd1 + "-by-" + widthAdd1);

document.getElementById("heightAdd1widthAdd1").innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(textNode);
```

` but the output I get on the page overwrites it to only show '[object Text]' which still has the correct url link.

How can I get the url link text to read instead of '[object Text]', e.g. '101-by-51'? The fiddle example is here https://jsfiddle.net/qm9cLs0o/ if you delete lines 33 and 34 the original text in the html shows again. Hovering over the links show the urls are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create a textnode (line 33) , use innerText and output it directly, this is how I would do this line 34 should be :

```
document.getElementById("heightAdd1widthAdd1").innerText = heightAdd1 + "-by-" + widthAdd1;
```

Comment: I hadn't found this .innerText suggestion (second full weekend searching to solve this) Much appreciated, works well.